# Preserving Single Quotes in YAML File When Editing

Tags: go, yaml, marshalling, unmarshalling

I want to edit the value of certain keys in a YAML file while keeping the rest unchanged. I have written a snippet to insert some values for these keys, but the resulting new file does not maintain single quotes (`'`). How can I avoid this situation?

my code:

```golang
func updateVariables(nameValue, nameCluster string) error {
    
    yamlFile, err := os.ReadFile("path")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error reading YAML file: %v", err)
    }

    var config PipelineConfig

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &config)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error parsing YAML file: %v", err)
    }

    for i := range config.Variables {
        switch config.Variables[i].Name {
        case "app_name":
            config.Variables[i].Value = nameValue
        case "cluster_name":
            config.Variables[i].Value = nameCluster

        }
    }

    modifiedYAML, err := yaml.Marshal(&config,)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error converting structure to YAML: %v", err)
    }

    err = os.WriteFile("path", modifiedYAML, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error writing modified YAML file: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("File YAML modified.")
    return nil
}
```

my struct:

```golang
type PipelineConfig struct {
    Trigger   string `yaml:"trigger"`
    Variables []struct {
        Name  string `yaml:"name"`
        Value string `yaml:"value"`
    } `yaml:"variables"`
    
    Stages []struct {
        Template   string `yaml:"template"`
        Parameters struct {
            AppName       string `yaml:"app_name"`
            AppRepoBranch string `yaml:"app_repo_branch"`
            LocationEnv   string `yaml:"location_env"`
            ComponentName string `yaml:"component_name"`
            ClusterName   string `yaml:"cluster_name"`
        } `yaml:"parameters"`
    } `yaml:"stages"`
}
```

**file yaml before edit**

```
trigger: none

variables:
  - name: app_name
    value: '<name>'
  - name: cluster_name
    value: '<cluster>'
  - name: component_name
    value: '<component>'
  - name: location_env
    value: 'dev'


stages:
  - template: 'tem'
    parameters:
      app_name: '${{ variables.app_name }}'
      app_repo_branch: 'dev'
      location_env: '${{ variables.location_env }}'
      component_name: '${{ variables.component_name }}'
      cluster_name: '${{ variables.cluster_name }}'
```

**file yaml after edit**

```
trigger: none
variables:
    - name: app_name
      value: test
    - name: cluster_name
      value: test
    - name: component_name
      value: <component>
    - name: location_env
      value: dev

stages:
    - template: tem
      parameters:
        app_name: ${{ variables.app_name }}
        app_repo_branch: develop
        location_env: ${{ variables.location_env }}
        component_name: ${{ variables.component_name }}
        cluster_name: ${{ variables.cluster_name }}
```

As you can see, the single quotes disappear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yaml.Unmarshal` function unmarshal **yaml** value to a custom struct without metadata (**style**, **kind**, etc.).
`yaml.Marshal` function under processing on a custom struct set metadata values as default. To get access metadata's fields, need to use [`yaml.Node`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Node).

In your case `Value` field has [`yaml.Style`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Style) equal `yaml.SingleQuotedStyle`

[image]

To get access to it (don't lose after unmarshalling), change `Value` field type to [`yaml.Node`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Node).

```golang
Variables []struct {
    Name  string    `yaml:"name"`
    Value yaml.Node `yaml:"value"`
} `yaml:"variables"`
```

```golang
for i := range config.Variables {
    switch config.Variables[i].Name.Value {
    case "app_name":
        config.Variables[i].Value.Value = nameValue
    case "cluster_name":
        config.Variables[i].Value.Value = nameCluster
    }
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/bafwR4KGHX8)</kbd>

Comment: By following your suggestions I was able to solve it, thank you for your clear and comprehensive answer!